# 2 Visual Studios Launching 2 different IIS Express Servers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have one .net core Front end project and one web api project.
If I open 2 visual studios, one with each of them and try to debug, they launch 2 different instances of IIS Express and I keep having CORS problems.

Can someone help me here? I tried all basic CORS code configurations on the applications startup and nothing works.

Worth to note that I dont think I had multiple IIS Express before, I think it launched all in one...

Comment: how do you know that IIS express have 2 instances?
and what CORS configuration have you tried?

Comment: Yes, two web applications require one IIS server instance each. There is nothing unusual about this. Since they are separate applications, they cannot run on the same server & port.